# calling functions simultaneously in google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

how do i call functions simultaneously in google scripts
This is my code right now

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl( " https://docs.google.com/a/emomentum-interactive.com/spreadsheets/d/1iW-AGK_BhhhIvLWH_VTacwdqTK_z3vpnMq2OPx4unDo/edit#gid=0");
    var sheet=ss.getSheets()[0];
     var range1= sheet.getRange(2, 3, 5, 3);
    var range2= sheet.getRange(7, 3,11, 9)


function test() {
   oneTest();
  twoTest();
 function oneTest()
  {

   var values1 = range1.getValues();
 Logger.log(values1);
  }
  function twoTest()
  {
  var values2 = range2.getValues();
 Logger.log(values2);
  }
    }
```

---

i wish to call oneTest() & twoTest() simultaneously

Comment: Is this bound to a spreadsheet?  Is it a Stand Alone App?  If it's a Stand Alone HTML App, then a `google.script.run` function call in an HTML Script tag can make a second call to the server before the first one is finished.  I don't think JavaScript on a Google server can **internally** call a second function before the first one is done.  There are situations where a user could quickly click two buttons, that cause something like two file uploads to happen at the same time.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like AJAX?  [Wikipedia - asynchronous javascript and XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: Like sandy said above.

Comment: Thank you Sandy Good it worked perfectly